# Apache always redirects http to https

Tags: https, apache-2.4

I am running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a site http://bharatkrishna.net/ and this is running off a machine at my home. I have forwarded ports 80 & 443 on my router.

As you can see, when you visit http://bharatkrishna.net/, it automatically gets redirected to https://bharatkrishna.net/.

I do not want it to get redirected to https for the whole site. I had intended to do it only for a particular sub-URL. ie. like only http://bharatkrishna.net/login should be https, rest should be http. How do I do it?

This is how I set up SSL on Apache by reading some tutorials online :

• In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ turn on SSLEngine, set cert locations

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                                                                                                                                               
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

                #LogLevel info ssl:warn                                                                                                                                                                                                       

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined                                                                                                                                                                               

                #   SSL Engine Switch:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.                                                                                                                                                                                 
                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/www_bharatkrishna_net.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/bharatkrishna.net.key

                SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
                SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bundle.crt

....
....

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

• Run the following commands:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

I copied `000-default.conf` to `default.conf` under sites-enabled and here is the contents of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: None of this shows anything that would cause a redirect. Include your configuration for port 80

Comment: @ETL, I have added my config for port 80 to the OP. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything doing redirect to https and I tried the link and it does not redirect me to https so I don't think you are having an issue. If you are redirected to https it might be that you are using Google Chrome and it checks if https is available and if so, switch (I believe I read somewhere once that Chrome does that).

Comment: yes it is Chrome! :-| I tried it on firefox and it stays in http. In Chrome even in incognito mode it switches to https.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration posted for Apache does not do any redirect from `http` to `https`. The switch to `https` is done by the browser in this case.

More information on this behavior can be found at:

- https://superuser.com/questions/606223/why-does-chrome-always-redirect-me-to-https-www-google-com
- https://superuser.com/questions/565409/chrome-how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https